# How can I sync differing primary key values on replicating execute?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, database-replication

I have two connections, `d` and `c`. Basically, whatever changes I do on certain models of `d`, it needs to be replicated at `c` as well. This is the code doing it:

```
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->isReplicate()) {
            $primaryKey = $this->_repository->getPrimaryKey();
            $replica = clone $this;
            $replica->setConnection(ConnectionManager::get('c'));
            $replica->execute();
            //$this->_repository->{$primaryKey} = $replica->getRepository()->{$primaryKey};
        }
        $result = parent::execute();
        return $result;
    }
```

The commented line would be responsible for syncing the primary keys, but of course this is not working, because `_repository` represents a `table`, yet, I need to apply row-level changes. How could I ensure that all new records created by this query will be synced?

This code is located in the `App\ORM\Query` namespace, which `extends` `Cake\ORM\Query`.

Comment: This is presumably to deal with inserts, to make sure that IDs are consistent between the two databases? But isn't this function also called for delete, update, etc., where this wouldn't make sense as the key will already be part of the query?

Comment: @GregSchmidt this is used for all the use-cases mentioned in your comment. The id syncing would be useful for inserts only, but I do not know how could I determine from a query object whether it's an insert. I also do not know how I would be able to get the entities changed. So, it is obvious that the commented line is incorrect. But I do not know how should it look alike. The docs was not providing this information.

Comment: This is a pretty obscure situation you're dealing with. Hopefully someone will have tips for you, but I think you'd be much better off looking at the [API documentation for the Query class](https://api.cakephp.org/4.0/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html), maybe the source code for that class, and get down and dirty with xdebug to examine what the various data structures that it holds are used for.

Comment: Now things begin to become complicated. Is there a reason why you're not using replication on DBMS level?

Comment: @ndm There are multiple physical servers, located on various machines, so we need some application logic on top of the RDBMS instances. Since the databases are huge, we need to make this kind of syncing whenever insert/update/delete happens, if possible, so we strongly prefer doing this when the application changes data rather than in a cron job. The syncing works nicely on `save`, because there is an implementation of `beforeSave` for a behavior and that's accessing the entities. But the problem is that this does not seem to be simple with `execute`.

Comment: @GregSchmidt thanks! Maybe the `_execute` method will be of help, as it is returning a `ResultSet`. Maybe `_transformQuery` on the `clone` can ensure a pk default value. `clause` returns a clause, in the case of `insert` it returns an array with the table and columns, maybe I can combine `clause` and `_transformQuery`. `getIterator` returns some iterable result, maybe it's helpful. The worst-case scenario is to retrieve the `sql` and inject into the generated query text the column name and value. I'm not an expert of CakePHP, so there might be more elegant approaches than my brutish solutions.

Comment: The above was mined from Cake 4.0. Cake 3.0 is much more restricted in its abilities.

Comment: I thought that "multiple physical servers, located on various machines" was sort of exactly what server-side replication is for?

Comment: @GregSchmidt 1. the kind of structural change that you propose would be the decision of the owner, so even if I would agree, it would not be relevant to the problem. 2. Solving the problem has theoretical significance, so changing the approach as a solution here would bypass solving the problem. 3. Periodical db syncing is already part of the project, but we need to apply the changes live whenever possible, so that the dbs are kept in sync while being fully operational between two synchronizations. 4. I have worked out a solution yesterday and plan to write an answer tomorrow.

Comment: @GregSchmidt 5. When a record is inserted into a table at d (or updated or removed), then syncing for that small change the whole table would make no sense in terms of resource usages and performance. 6. Doing a sync frequently is not an option in view of the need for live consistency and the slow nature of syncing a table/database at various places. 7. This is not the domain of replication. There is d1-d10, each having their own records for the affected tables, yet, c contains them all. So di contains a subset of the records at c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue with the code that follows (the logic is explained in the comments):

```
    /**
     * Overrides a method with the same name to handle synchronizations with c
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        //Some tables need replication. If this is such a table, then we need to perform some extra steps. Otherwise we would just call the parent
        //Method
        if ($this->isReplicate()) {
            //Getting the table
            $table = $this->_repository->getTable();
            //Replicating the query
            $replica = clone $this;
            //Setting the connection of the replica to c, because we need to apply the district changes to central
            $replica->setConnection(ConnectionManager::get('c'));
            //We execute the replica first, because we will need to refer c IDs and not the other way around
            $replica->execute();
            //If this is an insert, then we need to handle the ids as well
            if (!empty($this->clause('insert'))) {
                //We load the primary key's name to use it later to find the maximum value
                $primaryKey = $this->_repository->getPrimaryKey();
                //We get the highest ID value, which will always be a positive number, because we have already executed the query at the replica
                $maxID = $this->getConnection()
                              ->execute("SELECT {$primaryKey} FROM {$table} ORDER BY {$primaryKey} DESC LIMIT 0, 1")
                              ->fetchAll('assoc')[0][$primaryKey];

                //We get the columns
                $columns = $this->clause('values')->getColumns();
                //In order to add the primary key
                $columns[] = $primaryKey;
                //And then override the insert clause with this adjusted array
                $this->insert($columns);
                //We get the values
                $values = $this->clause('values')->getValues();
                //And their count
                $count = count($values);
                //There could be multiple rows inserted already into the replica as part of this query, we need to replicate all their IDs, without
                //assuming that there is a single inserted record
                for ($index = 0; $index < $count; $index++) {
                    $values[$index][$primaryKey] = $maxID - $count + $index + 1;
                }
                //We override the values clause with this adjusted array, which contains PK values as well
                $this->clause('values')->values($values);
            }
            //We nevertheless execute the query in any case, independently of whether it was a replicate table
            //If it was a replicate table, then we have already made adjustments to the query in the if block
            return parent::execute();
        }
    }
```